# Unable to connect my Chromecast with my custom receiver

Tags: react-native, google-cast, react-native-google-cast

I'm following this guide: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-receiver#4 to create a custom receiver. Unfortunately when I try to use the cactool for testing: https://casttool.appspot.com/cactool/ I always get and error regarding my device id: Failed to cast, please try again later. In the browser I get:

[image]

My application id: `8FEE03DD`

Status: *Published*

Chromecast serial id: `8917AD6D304`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "is_device_registered" error is caused by the Cast Debug Logger calls which don't work to run in a browser (since it isn't running on the Chromecast device and thus can't find it).

After many iterations and testing I have noticed the following common causes for "Failed to cast. Please try again" while using the code labs setup:

Chromecast caches the application data, so if you for instance updates the Receiver App URL the device has to be restarted before the new URL is used
Ngrok session times out (solved by restarting `ngrok` and updating the Receiver App URL in the Cast Developer Console)
Observe if you see GET requests from the Chromecast in the `http-server` console (my CC gen 3 has 'Linux armv71' etc in User-Agent). If so, the Receiver App is configured correctly and your issue is with the code (HTML, js, etc)

Comment: Still getting the same error but after I manually reboot my chromecast I managed to connect to it. Basically, every time I change any configuration in Google Cast SDK Developer Console I need to manually reboot it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Correct, turning on and off the Chrome cast seem to clear the cached receiver application data, otherwise the changed settings are not picked up.